# Is it possible to configure grovel.exe to ignore specified directories?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Is it possible to disable grovelling of particular directories? If so how?

My understanding of grovel is that it reduces file duplication by having one copy of the file and multiple links to it.

We have a problem where our software occasionally fails to open a file (Paradox DB). Using FileMon we can see that grovel.exe is accessing the files our program is trying to update, so the initial thought is that maybe that's causing our problem. If possible we would like to configure grovel so that it doesn't process our data directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like [this article (How to exclude directories from the Single Instance Store Groveler)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272149/EN-US/) is probably what you're looking for. I'm not sure that it's actually causing your problem but I would definitely be wary of doing SIS on a shared-file database such as the one you describe.

Comment: @Evan, I agree, we weren't aware the client was running SIS on the same box as our software. Usually we have a dedicated machine. Your suggestion did the trick, thanks.

Comment: The page link in the answer has gone, but there's a copy here
https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php?title=Microsoft_KB_Archive/272149